# for my c++ project, I created subfolder in eclipse , how to i include it into main?

Tags: c++

I want to include Friend.h file, I created a folder called friend and placed it in there.I now want to include into my main file. However eclipse does not recognize this:

```
#include "friend/Friend.h"
```

I tried looking through some sample code but still couldnt figure it out.

Comment: Is the `friend` directory inside the same directory as your main file? Or is the main file in another subdirectory?

Comment: no, friend is not in the same directory as main

Comment: main is in the src folder.

Comment: ops i mean main is in the composition folder.

Answer (score 0):

just fixed the problem, i moved main out side of the compistion folder inside the src folder.